# Javascript if statement for user input

Tags: javascript, if-statement, random, datatable

Need help figuring out how fix this if statement.  This is going to ask a question and display 4 dog images that need to display at the same time.  The user then clicks on one of the images then they will change again to new images.

```
var allDogs = getColumn("Dogs", "Name");
var allDogsPicturesList = getColumn("Dogs", "Image");
var questionNumber;
var dogImage;
var dogName;
var correctDog;
var userChoice;
var score;
setScreen("startScreen");
onEvent("readyButton", "click", function() {
  setScreen("quizScreen");
  gameQuestionsAndEnd();
});
onEvent("dog1", "click", function() {
  userChoice = getImageURL("dog1");
  gameQuestionsAndEnd();
});
onEvent("dog2", "click", function() {
  userChoice = getImageURL("dog1");
  gameQuestionsAndEnd();
});
onEvent("dog3", "click", function() {
  userChoice = getImageURL("dog1");
  gameQuestionsAndEnd();
});
onEvent("dog4", "click", function() {
  userChoice = getImageURL("dog1");
  gameQuestionsAndEnd();
});

function gameQuestionsAndEnd(answerRight, answerWrong) {
  dogName = (randomNumber(0, allDogs.length - 1));
  dogImage = (randomNumber(0, allDogsPicturesList.length - 1));
  correctDog = allDogsPicturesList[dogName];
  answerRight = dogName;
  var box = randomNumber(1, 4);
  setText("dogBeingGuessed", "Which dog is a " + "\n" + allDogs[dogName]);
  for (var w = 0; w <= 10; w++) {
    setProperty("dog" + box, "image", allDogsPicturesList[dogName]);
    if ("dog1" == allDogs[dogName]) {
      setProperty("dog2", "image", getImageURL(randomNumber(0, allDogsPicturesList.length)));
      setProperty("dog3", "image", getImageURL(randomNumber(0, allDogsPicturesList.length)));
      setProperty("dog4", "image", getImageURL(randomNumber(0, allDogsPicturesList.length)));
      questionNumber = questionNumber + 1;
    } else if ("dog2" == dogName) {
      setProperty("dog1", "image", randomNumber(0, allDogsPicturesList.length));
      setProperty("dog3", "image", randomNumber(0, allDogsPicturesList.length));
      setProperty("dog4", "image", randomNumber(0, allDogsPicturesList.length));
      questionNumber = questionNumber + 1;
    } else if ("dog3" == dogName) {
      setProperty("dog2", "image", randomNumber(0, allDogsPicturesList.length));
      setProperty("dog1", "image", randomNumber(0, allDogsPicturesList.length));
      setProperty("dog4", "image", randomNumber(0, allDogsPicturesList.length));
      questionNumber = questionNumber + 1;
    } else if ("dog4" == dogName) {
      setProperty("dog2", "image", randomNumber(0, allDogsPicturesList.length));
      setProperty("dog3", "image", randomNumber(0, allDogsPicturesList.length));
      setProperty("dog1", "image", randomNumber(0, allDogsPicturesList.length));
      questionNumber = questionNumber + 1;
    }
    if (answerRight == userChoice) {
      score = score + 1;
    }
    if (answerWrong) {
      score = score - 1;
    }
    questionNumber = questionNumber + 1;
  }
  if (questionNumber == 10) {
    setScreen("screen1");
  }
}
```

Tried copying other code to fix and asking for help from different programmers.

Comment: `gameQuestionsAndEnd()` expects 2 arguments. You're not passing the arguments when you call it.

Comment: Every time you call that function you pick a different random dog before you compare the user's selection.

Comment: You need to split it up into two functions. The first function selects a random dog and saves that in a global variable, you do this at the beginning of the game. The second function checks the user's selection, you call it when the user clicks.

Comment: What's not working properly? What is currently happening and what should happen instead? Also, you're passing any values into `gameQuestionsAndEnd()` when you call it from your event listeners.

Comment: The app is only showing one image at a time and its the right image. Its not displaying three other random images mixed in at the same time.  I'm not going to do the second function yet. I'm just trying to get the first part to work.

Comment: This part is allowing for a click on the app but will only bring one dog image up at a time.  It should show 4 dog images, allow for the user to click on one of the images, then change to a new question with 4 new dog images.   

    if ("dog1"==allDogs[dogName]) {
      setProperty("dog2", "image", getImageURL(randomNumber(0,allDogsPicturesList.length)));
      setProperty("dog3", "image", getImageURL(randomNumber(0,allDogsPicturesList.length)));
      setProperty("dog4", "image", getImageURL(randomNumber(0,allDogsPicturesList.length)));
      questionNumber = questionNumber+1;